# Weight restriction for carry on baggage in Delta airline

Tags: hand-luggage, delta-air-lines

I will be travelling to New York, USA from Berlin, Germany using Delta airline and I checked the restriction of carry on available [here](https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/during-your-trip/carry-on.html). It is said that there is no weight restriction, but is it true in reality? If so then I would like to put my backpack and laptop to my carry on luggage so it probably could weight around 10 kgs.

Comment: The page you linked on the airline's website seems quite clear "No maximum weight applies to carry-on baggage except in the below stations:" - is there a reason you doubt the airline's statement of their own policies?

Comment: I recently discovered that some European airlines, such as Swiss Air, have a carry-on bag weight limit. This is probably the OP’s experience.

Comment: I would actually sa that ***even though their web page literally states no weight restriction***, IMO if it is "incredibly heavy" they, in fact, will simply not permit it.  (And why should they?  It's a safety risk, so, who cares about some web site?)  {Note that in extremis - of course - pilots and other senior staff have absolute, total, arbitrary power to make safety decisions.}

Comment: Again FWIW - you will have absolutely no problem with 10kg. That is commonplace.

Comment: Since there is a size restriction, it is ok to have no weight restrictions.

Comment: @ChrisH since I have never met any airlines that do not have weight restriction so I am not sure whether it actually is like that in the practice. Airlines like Qatar even they are so strict with their weight restriction that always need to be careful with this stuff

Comment: @DoxyLover is it normal for american airlines to not have weight restrictions? I think other airlines have this weight restriction of 7/8 kgs

Comment: @Fattie that's true as the final decision will be from the airport and airline staffs so better to be safe than sorry (which means I need to pay for the checked in baggage etc)

Comment: OK, I would just say, a few laptops is nothing for carry on!  I normally travel very light (ie, with nothing at all), but I am right now sitting at a Starbucks in a terminal with a carry on so heavy I can hardly pick it up!  :)  (It is not large, it is just packed with laptops, gifts, and crap!)  I''m confident you will have no problem w/ what you are envisaging.  Good luck!  :)

Comment: @IhsanHaikal In many years of flying domestically in the United States, I’ve never seen stated weight limits on carry-on bags, only on checked luggage.

Comment: @DoxyLover so hopefully the same rule applies for international flight as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own research on Delta's web site is clear:

> **CARRY-ON WEIGHT RESTRICTIONS**
>
> No maximum weight applies to carry-on baggage except in the below stations:
>
> - Singapore, Singapore - Changi International Airport (SIN) carry on should not exceed 15 lbs. (7kgs)
> - Beijing - Beijing Capital International Airport (PEK) Civil Aviation Administration of China (CAAC) requires that domestic hand carry bags should not exceed 10kgs. Individual carrier rules apply for international flights.
> - Shanghai - Pudong International Airport (PVG) carry on should not exceed 22lbs. (10kgs)
>
> **CARRY-ON SIZE RESTRICTIONS**
>
> It won’t fit. Three words you don’t want to hear when trying to board. To avoid delays and possible checked bag fees, follow these size requirements:
>
> - Baggage may not exceed 45 linear inches (or 114 cm) in combined length, width and height, including any handles and wheels, with the exception of small musical instruments that fit in the overhead compartment space or under-seat space available at the time of boarding
> - Baggage must meet carry on size limits (approximately 22" x 14" x 9" or 56 x 35 x  23 cm). Reference size check templates located at ticket counters and gates.
>
> Passengers traveling on Delta Connection flights, and only those flights with fifty (50) seats or less, are only permitted to carry personal items on board the aircraft due to limited overhead space. Personal items must be able to fit securely under the seat in front of the passenger. All carry-on bags within Delta's size restrictions will be gate checked, free of charge, during the boarding process and returned upon deplaning. Please ensure that a pink Gate Claim/Planeside tag is securely attached to the carry-on item. Assistive devices are not subject to this restriction.

Comment: Yes I understand but I am asking whether in reality/practice this would be different or not.